# VM doesn't exit when the code is finished

Tags: hibernate, virtual-machine, exit

I'm performing some update transactions with hibernate. But after finishing all the job, the VM doesn't exit except explicitly calling the exit() method. My code is here :

```
BaseDao baseDao = new BaseDao();
    List<Papers> list = baseDao.find("from Papers");
    int i = 0;
    for (Papers p : list) {
        p.setAbstext(p.getAbstext().replaceAll("<br>", "").replaceAll("</br>", ""));
        baseDao.update(p);
        System.out.println(i++);
    }
```

and the thread dump is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code says really nothing. The reason of such behavior using Hibernate  can be that you don't close a session factory.

Comment: But all my methods in _BaseDao_ will close the session it opens in the finally block.

Comment: @zhongwei Not a session, but a session factory!

Comment: Yes, I forgot closing session factory. Is it saying that I must close the session factory after initializing an object of _BaseDao_?

Comment: @zhongwei You should close a session factory before your application stop.